# putImageData on a loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, putimagedata

I'm trying to build a beautiful graphic image (animated!), calculating a color for each pixel on a screen and then showing all the pixels at once. So, I'm using a putImageData function on a loop.

But for some reason it doesn't work. Only the last iteration can be seen on a screen (after 1-2 sec).

I've tried to use FillRect after each iteration, but it didn't help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full Screen Canvas Test</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>

    <script>
        (function () {
            canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");              
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
            step = 1;

            function doit() {   
                rx = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
                ry = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
                gx = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
                gy = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
                bx = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
                by = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);                                               

                var canvasData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

                for (var i = 0; i < canvas.width; i+=step) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < canvas.height; j+=step) {
                        po = 2;
                        rd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rx - i, po)+Math.pow(ry - j, po)));
                        gd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(gx - i, po)+Math.pow(gy - j, po)));
                        bd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bx - i, po)+Math.pow(by - j, po)));
                        maxd = 1400;
                        r = Math.floor((1 - rd/maxd)*255);
                        g = Math.floor((1 - gd/maxd)*255);
                        b = Math.floor((1 - bd/maxd)*255);

                        var index = (i + j * canvas.width) * 4;

                        canvasData.data[index + 0] = r;
                        canvasData.data[index + 1] = g;
                        canvasData.data[index + 2] = b;
                        canvasData.data[index + 3] = 255;


                    }
                }

                ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);

            }       

            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
            doit();
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: When I run your code I see an entire canvas filled with varying colours (like a gradient from red to green) is this not what you expect?

Comment: I expect it to be done 8 times, not 1.

Comment: Adding a wait interval of 1000 after each iteration doesn't help...

Comment: If you comment out all of the `doit()` method calls and leave the first one, it gives a different result, then if you have two `doit()` calls, you get a different result again. So, it seems that it is happening 8 times

Comment: Yes. But only the last iteration of `doit()` is visualized.. edit: I expect to see 8 different images in a row, but I can see only the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInveral()` to call your `doit()` function multiple times with a time delay between each call. The issue with your current method is that it is running all your `doit()` results in one iteration, and then displaying the last one only as it overwrites your previous results. Thus, you need to display the results of each sequentially.

See working example below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Full Screen Canvas Test</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>

  <script>
    (function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
      step = 1;

      function doit() {
        rx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        gx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        gy = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        by = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

        var canvasData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < canvas.width; i += step) {
          for (var j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += step) {
            po = 2;
            rd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rx - i, po) + Math.pow(ry - j, po)));
            gd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(gx - i, po) + Math.pow(gy - j, po)));
            bd = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bx - i, po) + Math.pow(by - j, po)));
            maxd = 1400;
            r = Math.floor((1 - rd / maxd) * 255);
            g = Math.floor((1 - gd / maxd) * 255);
            b = Math.floor((1 - bd / maxd) * 255);

            var index = (i + j * canvas.width) * 4;

            canvasData.data[index + 0] = r;
            canvasData.data[index + 1] = g;
            canvasData.data[index + 2] = b;
            canvasData.data[index + 3] = 255;

          }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
      }
      
      // Use setInterval to display the images sequentially (every 1000 m/s (every second))
      let showImg = setInterval(doit, 1000);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow. For some reason it didn't work for me. Need time to analyze.

Comment: @RomanNastenko Maybe you didn't set a big enough interval? I used `1000` so it triggers the `doit()` method every second (every 1000 m/s)

Comment: And what if I want to run it endlessly? Does it work for you?

Comment: When I'm deleting `if(count < imgAmount-1)` part (all if) and leaving just `clearInterval(showImg);` - it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @RomanNastenko yes, that's even easier, give me a few min to fix

Comment: The `clearInterval` is what stops the loop, so leaving it in there will stop the loop. So, you need to remove that too. See updated version ^

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: Now I will try to make these light sources move :)

Comment: @RomanNastenko oh nice, I think that would look cool. Good luck!